# Simple adder and copy program in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a program that is just based on 3 instructions

In haskell, they will look like this.

```
-- DEL b        == empty box b

-- ADD b        == increment box b by 1

-- JEQ b1 b2 j  == if boxes b1 and b2 contain the same value, jump to instruction n

data Instruction
  = DEL {box :: Int} 
  | ADD {box :: Int}
  | JEQ {box1   :: Int, 
         box2   :: Int,
         jumpTo :: Int}
  deriving (Eq, Show)

type Program = [Instruction]
```

Users will input a starting list of values that represent the boxes starting from box1, with box0 being set aside for calculation purposes.

```
e.g. 
boxes = [0, 4, 6, 5, 12, 20]
```

I already have written the code on how the boxes will change when a program is executed, for example:

```
pgrm = [ADD 1, DEL 3, ADD 1, JEQ 1 2 4, CLR 4, ADD 4]
```

when pgrm is executed on boxes, the result would be

```
[0, 6, 6, 0, 13, 20]
```

But i am now trying to implement an adder and copy program using just the 3 instructions given.

```
-- Adds contents of box x and box y and puts it into box 1
addXY :: Int -> Int -> Program

-- copy the contents of box x to box y (leave box x unchanged)
copyBox :: Int -> Int -> Program
```

Is there any way I can implement these without changing the values in any other boxes, and only using the 3 instructions with an empty box0 to use for calculations? and how would that be done?

PS. I know this is more of a mathematical theory question rather than a coding question. Would appreciate if any math geniuses out there could help me out!

Comment: *"Is there any way I can implement these..."* Yes. Now what is your question?

Comment: Your `Instruction` looks weird to me.  Why does the instruction store the data it is operating on?

Comment: @HenriMenke It doesn't, it contains the box number, like a pointer. It really should be a `Word` rather than an `Int`.

Comment: This is a nice exercise, but SO is not a "solve this for me" service. Further, are you sure you can't change the values in any other box? Using a "tmp" auxiliary (scratch) box could be quite useful here.

Comment: @chi box 0 is "set aside for calculation purposes"

Comment: @AJFarmar what would be an ideal algorithm for this?

Comment: Note that, if you have a box X, you can loop X times by resetting box 0, then incrementing box 0 as many times as needed to make it equal to X. In this loop you can perform (X times) any other operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I can implement these without changing the values in any other boxes

The copy routine is straight forward. You can use box 0 as a counter and copy the value by creating a loop that increments the destination box `x` times after resetting it to zero. One problem arises while implementing the loop: you need either an unconditional jump instruction or a conditional jump with a negated condition.

Example 1: you can emulate an unconditional jump by comparing the counter and the destination box, which have always the same value within the loop:

```
copyBox :: Int -> Int -> Program
copyBox x y = [ DEL 0      -- 0: clear box 0, we use it as a counter
              , DEL y      -- 1: clear destination box
              , JEQ 0 x 6  -- 2: counter reaches value in x => copying is finished
              , ADD 0      -- 3: increment counter
              , ADD y      -- 4: increment destination
              , JEQ 0 y 2  -- 5: always true, hence jump back to beginning of loop
              , DEL 0      -- 6: clear box 0 to clean up
              ]
```

Example 2: Here is a variant, that uses a hypothetical `JNEQ` instruction:

```
copyBox :: Int -> Int -> Program
copyBox x y = [ DEL 0      -- 0: clear box 0, we use it as a counter
              , DEL y      -- 1: clear destination box
              , JEQ 0 x 6  -- 2: x is zero => skip the copy loop
              , ADD 0      -- 3: increment counter
              , ADD y      -- 4: increment destination
              , JNEQ 0 x 3 -- 5: counter not equal x => one more iteration
              , DEL 0      -- 6: clear box 0 to clean up
              ]
```

For the `addXY` routine you either need this `JNEQ` instruction or - if you use the emulation trick of the first example - a further temporary working cell. I currently see no possibility to implement `addXY` with the provided three instructions and the condition that no box except 0 (temporary) and 1 (result) are modified.